# Can I use my own documentclass (custom.cls) with latex2html?

Tags: latex2html, documentclass, tug

I posted a question similar to this on latex2html@tug.org, but lack of response makes me wonder whether the list still has active members.

For production of stand-alone documents in PDF format, I have been using a custom LaTeX documentclass (tgba.cls) which is based on article.cls.

Now I wish to produce similar documents as web pages, so I tried running latex2html on the same .tex files.  latex2html does produce web pages, but it complains:

```
No implementation found for style `tgba'
Unknown commands: ArticleTitle journalheader
```

and the web pages lack the title and header.

The first two lines of tgba.cls are:

```
\ProvidesPackage{tgba}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
```

(1) Is there a way to make tgba.cls visible to latex2html?

(2) Should I add the needed definitions to article.cls?

(3) Should I add the needed definitions to the head of the .tex file of each document?

Comment: Have you tried TeX4ht? It uses LaTeX for the conversion, so it can support custom packages and commands.

Comment: I did consider TeX4ht, and I decided that latex2html was a better approach; but perhaps I should reconsider.  But now I think that, inasmuch as a fancy header is not needed for a web page, the proper approach is to use latex2html with article.cls or book.cls to create web pages on which are posted descriptions and links to articles in PDF format.

Comment: Why did you decided latex2html to be better? I am just curious as TeX4ht maintainer :) Anyway, TeX4ht supports custom commands, so it should work with your class ideally out of the box. But there can be issues, sometimes there can be clash between packages, etc. I would need the code of your class and text document to tell more.

Comment: I am happy to learn that TeX4ht is maintained; somehow, in searching for a non-WordPress approach to a web site, I got the impression that TeX4ht had been abandoned, and that latex2html was in wider use.  But now it appears that I need to change course.  Years ago I was happily running with (if I recall correctly) hyperlatex, and whenever I added or removed material, a makefile took care of all the details, generating a fresh website in its entirety.  Then, in the transition to HTML5 and CSS, hyperlatex was abandoned, and eventually my automated system quit functioning.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: That's bad. It is true that many sites link to the old documentation, which is full of obsolete information. here is the real project page with ChangeLog and some new information: https://tug.org/tex4ht/. And see also make4ht documentation: https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html